# DOM PHP - Insertar etiqueta <a> dentro de <ul> <li>

Tags: php, dom

Estoy haciendo un árbol con el contenido de un FTP. Simplemente muestro todo el contenido de una carpeta organizado por ul > li. Lo que necesito ahora, es añadir la etiqueta < a > dentro de los < li > para luego añadirle un href para descargar el elemento (esto ya lo sé hacer), pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Lo estuve intentando de varias formas pero no lo consigo.

Necesitaría algo así:

```
<ul>
 <li> <a> XYZ </a> </li>
 ...
 <ul class="child">
  <li> XYZ
   <ul class="child">
    <li> <a> XYZ </a> </li>
    ...
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <li> <a> XYZ </a> </li>
 ...

</ul>
```

---

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                $dom = new DomDocument("1.0");
                $list = $dom->createElement("ul");
                $dom->appendChild($list);
                $node = $list;
                $depth = 0;
                foreach($objects as $name => $object){  
                    if ($objects->getDepth() == $depth){
                        //the depth hasnt changed so just add another li
                        $li = $dom->createElement('li', $object->getFilename());
                        $node->appendChild($li);
                    }
                    elseif ($objects->getDepth() > $depth){
                        //the depth increased, the last li is a non-empty folder 
                        $li = $node->lastChild;
                        $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');
                        $ul->setAttribute('class', 'child');
                        $li->appendChild($ul);
                        $ul->appendChild($dom->createElement('li', $object->getFilename()));
                        $node = $ul;
                    }
                    else{
                        //the depth decreased, going up $difference directories
                        $difference = $depth - $objects->getDepth();
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $difference; $difference--){
                            $node = $node->parentNode->parentNode;
                        }
                        $li = $dom->createElement('li', $object->getFilename());
                        $node->appendChild($li);
                    }
                    $depth = $objects->getDepth();
                }
                echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? ¿Probaste con appendChild()?

Comment: Sí, pero colocar uno dentro de otro no me acaba de funcionar. Añado una alternativa que me ha sido útil para salir del paso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné provisionalmente utilizando algunos "echo" en el segundo condicional que era el más importante, mientras busco la solución óptima con una buena práctica:

```
elseif ($objects->getDepth() > $depth){
 //the depth increased, the last li is a non-empty folder
 $li = $node->lastChild;
 $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');
 $ul->setAttribute('class', 'child');
 echo '<ul>';
 $li->appendChild($ul);
 echo '<li><a '.$url.' >'.$object->getFilename().'</a>';
 echo '</ul>';
 $node = $ul;
}
```